# Is there a way to hide the masking lines when using Texture Paint with masking enabled?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I'm getting into painting textures onto my models using Blender's texture paint.  I like that Blender provides the 'face selection masking' button that lets me mask out faces that I don't want to accidentally paint.  However, when enabled this feature outlines all the selected faces with bold white lines - making it really difficult to see the results of my painting.  Is there a way to hide this overlay?

Comment: im not sure , but select the faces you dont want to paint and press "H" , and if you want to unhide them press alt - H

Comment: To hide texture borders, I had to disable mipmaps in Blender menu "File" -> "User settings" -> "System". I am not sure if you had the same problem but it may help other people.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there is no such option, which disables the white lines.
In *Weight Paint Mode* you have an option to display vertices instead of edges, but in *Texture Paint Mode* there is no option like this.

[image]

I think that using the *Clipping Border Tool* may be a good solution for you. Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and drag a mouse to select the portion of the model which you want to be visible.

[image]

You can rotate selected portion, and paint on it precisely. And the most important is, there are no lines that may disturb you :).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Well, just download the latest Blender. 
Hiding the masked texture painting lines was one of its features:

[Blender 2.73 Release Notes](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.73/Painting)

[image]